# Django OAuth sign up and get a token in the same view

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-authentication, django-oauth

I am trying to create a sign up view that can both register the user model according to the POST data, and that includes in the response both:

1. The created user data (i.e. `{'username': 'foo.bar', 'email': 'test@test.io'}`)
2. The token data (i.e. `{'expires_in': 36000, 'access_token': 'foo', 'scope': 'read write', 'token_type': 'Bearer', 'refresh_token': 'bar'}`)

So they don't have to login after signing up. I am trying to do so with this views.py:

```
import json

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

import requests

from rest_framework import permissions, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from accounts.serializers import UserSerializer, UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfile(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data) # data
        if user_profile.is_valid():
            user_profile.save() # returns User instance
            # ask for a token
            r = requests.post('http://myapp.com/auth/token',
                          data = {'client_id': '',
                                  'client_secret': '',
                                  'grant_type': 'password',
                                  'username': user_profile.user.username,
                                  'password': request.data['password']})
            response_dict = json.loads(r.text)
            response_dict['user_profile'] = user_profile.data
            return Response(response_dict, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(user_profile._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

however I don't know how am I supposed to get my provider's `client_id` and `client_secret` (I created my oauth2_provider application).

Am I supposed to get it as in `my_app = oauth2_provider.models.Application.objects.all()[0]` and then get them as `my_app.client_id` and `my_app.client_secret`? Is there a nicer way to do so?

Plus, has this any security flaws?

Thank you!